# How to restore MySQL database from external drive Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, backup, restore

How can I restore MySQL database from external drive without the dump file? I have the database folder but when I move it into the `datadir` directory with the other databases it says all the tables in the database don't exist. I also tried changing the `datadir` in `mysqld.cnf` but MySQL had an error while restarting the server after I did that.

> OS Version: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: when you have the **same** server version and this applies  for the subversion also, simply copy **all** files, but is t has to be the same version

Comment: what do you mean all files? like cnf files too?

Comment: the hole data directory including all files ibddata1  all temp simply everything

Comment: So everything in this directory? ```/var/lib/mysql```

Comment: yes all what it in it

Comment: Ok do I need to restart MySQL service?

Comment: Also, to the person that marked this as a duplicate, I do NOT have the dump file, nor can I create one.

Comment: yes of course, as you can't replace the directory during run time you have restart it and look in the mysql error log to see if something is a problem good luck